# Постоянное добавление новой строки в dataGridView1?

Tags: c#

Есть dataGridView1 и три textBox, в которые вносятся числа. в dataGridView 4 столбца. в первые 3 постоянно должны заноситься числа из 3-х тектБоксов, в четвёртый надо вывести их сумму. Как при новом вводе данных добавлять новую строку в dataGridView и складывать? Делаю так, но новые строки не добавляются:

```
    string[] info = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };
    for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
    {
        string sad = info[i];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value += sad;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, ваша_сумма);
```